# Get Parent of DOM Element Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I’d like to check whether a DOM element is a child of a specific DIV class regardless of the number of DIV/HTML between the element and the parent DIV.  I need to use JavaScript (not jQuery).  So if I had some HTML like this:

```
<div class="header grid-12">
  <!-- many levels of divs/html -->  
  <div class="section">
     <span id="id1">hello</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <!-- many levels of divs/html -->
  <span id="id2">goodbye</span>
</div>
```

I'd want to do something like this (logically that is):

```
var domID = document.getElementById("id1");
if (domID a child of 'header grid-12') {
 console.log('header grid-12 found');
}
```

I looked at parentNode children which would allow you to get all of the child nodes but I need to loop in reverse (parentnode parent if you will).  I'm thinking it's much faster to start at the child and go up as opposed starting at "header grid-12" and looping through hundreds/thousands of nodes.

Thanks

Comment: Does `parentElement` not meet your needs?

Comment: if you have 'header grid-12' stored in a variable called "headerGrid12" you can do if(domID.parentElement == headerGrid12)

Comment: Then you need to write a recursive function: `isAncestor(ancestor, node), though you could also do it iteratively in a non-recursive way`

Answer (score 2):

> The `Element.closest()` method returns the closest ancestor of the current element (or the current element itself) which matches the selectors given in parameter. If there isn't such an ancestor, it returns null.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

try this,

```
let parent = !!document.getElementById('id1').closest('.header.grid-12');
if(parent)
{
    console.log('parent found');
}
```

`domElement.closest('selector')` goes in reverse and return the nearest matching parent element.  This will save you from iteratiing through all `domChildElements`.

Comment: Some explanation as to why a particular solution addresses the issue is generally helpful, not only to the OP but to others in the future.